# Android app is crashing with Cursor db.rawQuery() call?

Tags: android, sqlite

So my app is pretty basic it's a customer app that's entering values into an SQLite database storing names,numbers, and addresses all strings. Now my insertion function seems to be working fine from what I can tell but my app crashes when I'm trying to call rawQuery in the function where I'm trying to return a string.

```
    public String returnString(String name) {

    String temp = "";

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] value = {name};

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    if(db.isOpen()) {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, value);

        c.moveToFirst();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null && c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")).equals(name)) {

                temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                break;
            }// if

        } // while

        c.close();
        db.close();
    } // if
    else{

        Log.i("Failure -> ", " DataBase failed to open.");
        temp = "ERROR";

    }
    return temp;
}
```

Basically you send in the name and it should return the whole column. But I can't figure out why my app is crashing at the following line...

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, value);
```

just for info here's my Insertion function with onCreate and onUpgrade...

```
    public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1; // version
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "customers.db"; // stored file name
public static final String TABLE_CUSTOMERS = "customers"; // name of table

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";

public DBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
} // constructor

// first time creation of db
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

    db.execSQL(query);

}

// on upgrade of db
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS);

    onCreate(db);

}

// add customer by custom container
public void addCustomer(StudentsDB customer) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, customer.get_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, customer.get_address());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, customer.get_email());
    values.put(COLUMN_PHONE, customer.get_phone());

    db.insert(TABLE_CUSTOMERS, null, values);

    db.close();

} // addCustomer

// delete all of table
public void dropTable() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS);

    db.close();

}

// return string with string
public String returnString(String name) {

    String temp = "";

    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_NAME + " = ?";
    String[] value = {name};

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();

    if (db.isOpen()) {

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, value);

        c.moveToFirst();

        while (c.moveToNext()) {

            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")) != null && c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")).equals(name)) {

                temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
                break;
            }// if

        } // while

        c.close();
        db.close();
    } // if
    else {

        Log.i("Failure -> ", " DataBase failed to open.");
        temp = "ERROR";

    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: please add your crash log here.

Comment: @Guruji Here you go, [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M7gbgXzr3zmOxlXBtf811A_KL8Gc9Zhj) Seems like it says I have no such table...so my onCreate is wrong?

Comment: your table is not create.

Comment: Yes but onCreate() method should be making the table no?

Comment: please add your sqlite helper snippet of code.

Comment: @Guruji here you go -> [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-dUydLdVUMeWoXnFuohdLanbdxnUBYv9) It's the full file, since the snip is above in the question.

Comment: Remove the trailing semicolon inside the create query.

Comment: @mkamran94 please check my ans.

Comment: Also according to sqlite docs, an integer primary key will automatically be auto incremented and using auto increment explicitly is bad for performance

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Change your table query trailing semicolon inside the create query  **")";**

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CUSTOMERS + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT NOT NULL + ")";
```

Comment: Wow thank you. that tiny thing had me going crazy all day!

Comment: The semicolon cannot the problem. It works with or without it. There was something else done (such as uninstalling the app) if a change like this resolved OP's problem.